# Convergence of $\sum a_n\frac{e^{nit}}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have some problems solving this exercise:
(assuming all the series taken on naturals)

Let $a_n$ be a bounded sequence and let $\sum a_n\frac{e^{nit}}{2^n}=\frac{\pi}{2}(1+e^{it})+4$ for every $t\in[0,2\pi)$.
Prove that $\sum a_n=\frac{3}{2}\pi+4$.

My attempt:
I take $f_n(z)= a_n\frac{e^{niz}}{2^n}$ and it is clear that $\sum f_n(z)$ define an holomorphic function in the upper plane cutted by $Img(z)=-i\log(2)$ (becouse of the bound for the sequence and the fact that reamains a geometric series of ratio $|\frac{e^{iz}}{2}|$ ).
So $f(z):=\sum f_n(z)$ is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}(1+e^{iz})+4$ for $t$ in $[0,2\pi)$ so by analytic continuation it is the same in the open upper plane.
My question is:
Why i can say that $\sum a_n$ is convergent?
(The problem, for me, really is to prove the first equality of $lim_{_{z\to z_0}}\sum f_n(z)=\sum f_n(z_0)=\sum a_n$ with $z_0=-i\log(2)$).
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. You are assuming that it converges when $z$ is of the form $\frac{e^{it}}2$ ($t\in[0,2\pi)$) and that then its sum is equal to $\frac\pi2(1+2z)+4$. Then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is the Taylor series of the entire function $z\mapsto\frac\pi2(1+2z)+4$. But the radius of convergence of any entire function centered at any complex number is $\infty$. And, by the Identity Theorem,$$(\forall z\in\Bbb C):\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n=\frac\pi2(1+2z)+4.$$Now, take $z=1$.

Comment: Is the fact that the sequence is bounded necessary?

Comment: I had no need for that assumption.